# How to delete values introduced on airflow through helm?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, minikube

```
helm install airflow . --namespace airflow -f my_values.yaml -f my_other_values.yaml
```

I executed the command from above but had to interrupt it, cannot re-execute it because gives me the error:

```
Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either [`helm uninstall`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_uninstall/) the existing release

```sh
helm uninstall airflow
helm install airflow . -n airflow -f values.dev.yaml ...
```

or use [`helm upgrade`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) to replace it with a new one

```sh
helm upgrade airflow . -n airflow -f values.dev.yaml ...
```

Both will have almost the same effect.  You can [`helm rollback`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_rollback/) the upgrade but the uninstall discards that history.

Mechanically, `helm install` and `helm upgrade` just send Kubernetes manifests to the cluster, and from there the cluster takes responsibility for actually doing the work.  Unless the chart has time-consuming hook jobs, it's actually possible that your current installation is fine and you don't need to do any of this (even if `helm install --wait` didn't report the Deployments were ready yet).

(The commands above assume you're using the current version 3 of Helm.  Helm 2 has slightly different syntax and commands, but at this point is unsupported and end-of-lifed.)